# Npgsql C# throwing Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object suddenly

Tags: c#, database, winforms, postgresql, npgsql

I have a C# winform application and everything was working fine, but after prolonged use of the app I started getting this error

```
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
```

The error is from a function that executes every 5 seconds to get a list of names from the database

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(
            String.Format("select pid,name from queue order by id"), conn);
NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    queue[(int)reader["pid"]] = (string)reader["name"];
}
```

This list contains names in a queue and needs to be updated in as short time as possible

From what I have read, it seems like a new limitation from .net framework..

Any better way to do this or a workaround to avoid this error?

Edit: and btw, I dont understand the limitation! I added a function that enters more than 100000 entries into the database and I didn't get this error!

Comment: Can you please provide a full stacktrace and not just the exception text?

Comment: Also, you should dispose all disposable objects as @Dag says below (even if that's not the cause of the exception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you dispose reader and cmd after use? This *could* be memory leak-related where the postgres-provider ends up running out of an internal resource after some time.

You should follow a using-pattern like described on their homepage: http://www.npgsql.org/doc/

```
using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(
        String.Format("select pid,name from queue order by id"), conn))
{
    using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            queue[(int)reader["pid"]] = (string)reader["name"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just close the connection. conn.close() Isn't that enough?

Comment: It should, it depends on the implementation. I always wrap my database objects (SQL server) with using to be sure, and that's proven to be very robust in production. In your case, unless you dispose the reader it might keep a reference to the connection, preventing it from being disposed. Depending on the quality of the provider you might even have to both close and dispose the objects.

Comment: I changed all my code into wrapping it with using, and I have yet to receive the error once.. Not sure if you are right or I have yet to receive the error later, but I will mark this as the answer.. Thanks for your time and effort, I aprreciate it